# UIImagePickerController thumbnail of video which is pick up from library

Tags: video, uiimagepickercontroller, thumbnails

I am trying to get the thumbnail of the video which is pick up from library using the UIImagePickerController.

Here is my code. I can get the the thumbnail of video if I using the camera to record a video. But I can not get the thumbnail if I pick up a video from the library. Anybody know why?

```c
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
    {
        NSURL *mediaUrl = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

        MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:mediaUrl];
        moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
        UIImage *thumbnail = [[moviePlayer thumbnailImageAtTime:0.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame] retain];
        [imageView setImage:thumbnail];  //imageView is a UIImageView

        [moviePlayer release];
        [thumbnail release];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I had a semi-related problem, and eventually abandoned using MPMoviePlayer to generate thumbnails. Try using [AVAssetImageGenerator](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetImageGenerator_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVAssetImageGenerator) instead. Apple discusses using AVAssetImageGenerator to create thumbnails [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/01_UsingAssets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH7-SW1). Here is my own sample code, which grabs a single thumbnail image. You will need to include the AVFoundation framework.

```m
AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:vidPath options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *gen = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
gen.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
CMTime time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.0, 600);
NSError *error = nil;
CMTime actualTime;

CGImageRef image = [gen copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:&actualTime error:&error];
UIImage *thumb = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image];
CGImageRelease(image);
[gen release];
```

Answer (score 15):

The [AssetsLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/index.html) framework has exactly what you need with the `ALAssetsLibrary` and `ALAsset` classes. This code work for both photos and videos and the thumbnail image is exactly the same as you see in the picker.

```c
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [[ALAssetsLibrary new] assetForURL:info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:asset.thumbnail];
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        // handle error
    }];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Note that there is a bug on iOS 8 with Photo Stream albums, see [ALAssetsLibrary assetForURL: always returning nil for photos in “My Photo Stream” in iOS 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480526/alassetslibrary-assetforurl-always-returning-nil-for-photos-in-my-photo-stream/26526199#26526199) for a workaround.

Comment: On iOS 8 and later, Apple recommends using the [Photos framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014408) instead of ALAssetsLibrary. This would be a better approach than falling back to `enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:`.

Comment: I think that comment rather belongs to the linked question.

Answer (score 8):

```
func videoSnapshot(filePathLocal:URL) -> UIImage? {
    do
    {
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: filePathLocal)
        let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        imgGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        let cgImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImage(at:CMTimeMake(Int64(0), Int32(1)),actualTime: nil)
        let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        return thumbnail
    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        print("Error generating thumbnail: \(error)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Thhnaks for the soution

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 5** and above

```
func thumbnailForVideo(url: URL) -> UIImage? {
    let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
    let assetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    assetImageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true

    var time = asset.duration
    time.value = min(time.value, 2)

    do {
        let imageRef = try assetImageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)
        return UIImage(cgImage: imageRef)
    } catch {
        print("failed to create thumbnail")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3.1

I have create a class function and pass your url in param

```
class func captureThumbnail(withVideoURL videoURL:URL,secs:Int,preferredTimeScale scale:Int,completionHandler:((UIImage?) ->Void)?) -> Void
{
    //let seconds : Int64 = 10
    // let preferredTimeScale : Int32 = 1

    DispatchQueue.global().async {

        do
        {
            let asset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL)

            let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
            imgGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
            let cgImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImage(at:CMTimeMake(Int64(secs), Int32(scale)),actualTime: nil)
            let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
            completionHandler?(thumbnail)
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print("Error generating thumbnail: \(error)")
            completionHandler?(nil)
        }
    }
}
```