# Generating video thumbnails makes tableview slow

Tags: ios, uitableview, slowdown, video-thumbnails

I am generating thumbnail images for videos stored in my document directory and displaying it in a UITableview. This works but it makes my table view slow and jerky when I scroll. I have used GCD (dispatch_async) too but the result is the same. Can someone tell me how this can be properly implemented? How can I achieve this without having a slow, jerky tableview?

NOTE: I prefer to generate the thumbnails when needed rather than generating and storing several thumbnails when the video is first created.

Here is my code that generates the thumbnails using MPMoviePlayer Controller:

```
movie= [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:Path]];
thumbnail = [movie thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];[player stop];
[player stop];        
player = nil;
```

Comment: Use SDWebImage. it gives very smooth loading to images. https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: SDWebImage does NOT address my requirements at all. Again, the videos I am generating thumbnails for are local, in the document directory not on a remote server. Also, I can already generate thumbnails for photos without any issue, so it is just videos in the document directory

Comment: are you displaying images or videos in table view.  clearly state the issue.

Comment: My question covered the issue specifically: generate and display video thumbnails in tableview without slowing down the tableview. Pls read it again

Comment: Are you alloc'ing a new MPMoviePlayerController each time you make a thumbnail for each table view cell? Are you using dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier properly (or at all)?

Comment: I allocate each time I need to generate a thumbnail. However, when the table cell is created, I am dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:. I am able to generate thumbnails for several hundreds of images without slowdown in the same tableview but the videos are the ones that cause the slow down.

Comment: Right, but init'ing MPMoviePlayerController with a video involves more overhead. If you're just getting thumbnails from one video at a time pull that line out so it doesn't repeatedly load the video into memory. (As a test pull it out of the piece of code you quoted above and put it in a method that just happens once before the table cells start getting filled - maybe the viewWillAppear method)

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion but note that this absolutely has to be inside tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:. There's no way to add the statement outside this method. The dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: ensures that I am re-using existing cells and if it already existed on the screen, it doesn't get alloc'ed repeatedly. I think the answer lies around blocks (GCD) but my implementation of blocks is still slow while it is fast for the images (several hundreds of MBs).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution at [UIImagePickerController thumbnail of video which is pick up from library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719135/uiimagepickercontroller-thumbnail-of-video-which-is-pick-up-from-library) solves my problem. To get a very fast response, implement the code using GCD (blocks)